# Python - getting a unique list

Tags: python, unique

I am using the code below:

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 def recursiveUrl(url, link, depth):
     if depth == 5:
         return url
     else:
         print(link['href'])
         page = requests.get(url + link['href'])
         soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
         newlink = soup.find('a')
         if len(newlink) == 0:
             return link
         else:
             return link, recursiveUrl(url, newlink, depth + 1)

 def getLinks(url):
     page = requests.get(url)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
     links = soup.find_all('a')
     for link in links:
         links.append(recursiveUrl(url, link, 0))
     return links

 links = getLinks("https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/")

 def unique(links):

     uniqueValues = {}
     for i in links:
         uniqueValues.add(i)

     for i in uniqueValues:
         print(i)

 unique(links)
```

I have tried a number of ways of trying to print only unique entries but my output is a long list like the below I should ideally only print on of each unique entry:

Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I would assume that the links are not completely identical, this is the only explanation. Btw, you could also convert the list to a set, which can contain only unique items.

Comment: I quickly wrote and ran a very similar Python program using the method you did and it did indeed work perfectly fine. Have you verified that the links are perfectly identical, like @sammy suggested?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with a list like `[1, 1, 2]`. You need to make a [mre].

Comment: You need to **provide us a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**. Just give us a static list of say 10 URLs. It's not reproducible if you only show us an URL to the BeautifulSoup code. On SO you're required to provide an MCVE for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code `uniqueValues.add(i)` as you set it to `dict`
 previously and `dict` has no add !

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

links = set()
for item in soup.findAll('a'):
    item = item.get('href')
    links.add(item)

for item in links:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a list try using a set. That way you don't have multiple instances of the same website.

```
uniqueValues = {}
for i in links:
    uniqueValues.add(i)

for i in uniqueValues: 
    print(i)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203865/discussion-on-answer-by-nathaniel-blanquel-python-getting-a-unique-list).